# *sn > n (in Latin)

Tags: historical-linguistics, latin, sound-change

The older consonant cluster **sn-** loses its  *s* in Latin:

***n**ix* "snow" vs. English ***sn**ow*

*cē**n**a* "supper" vs. older Latin *ce**sn**a*

Two questions:

1) Since word-medial *-sn-* was clearly lost within the history of Latin, is the same thought to be true of word-initial *sn-*?

(I'm pretty sure that *sn* > *n* is not pan-Italic, as I think there are attested forms with initial *sn-* from some of the non-Latin Italic languages, but I don't recall any examples of initial *sn-* within Latin.)

2) Is there thought to be any link between the changes *sn* > *n* and *gn* > *n* in Latin?

I ask because the latter change also seems to have happened within the history of Latin (***gn**ōtus* ~ ***n**ōtus* "known, recognized"), although it does not seem to have extended into word-medial environments at all (*i**gn**is* "fire", *li**gn**um* "wood", etc.).

Thanks

Comment: Word initial sn might go via hn, since "hnow" is a child speech substitute for "snow".

Comment: @GregLee What's strange is that there is no general change of s > h in Latin, but in Greek, which *did* undergo a s > h shift, there apparently wasn't a complete shift of sN > N (where N = any nasal). For example, there is a sporadic or dialectal alternation in Greek between _smikrós_ and _mikrós_ ("short"), the first of these being the older form (according to what I've heard).

Comment: Well, the change I mentioned in child speech is not the result of a change s > h.  It's from a progressive voicing assimilation of n to preceding s, then loss of the s conditioning factor.  "hnow" is just a way of writing that.

Comment: One possible explanation that comes to mind for variants like *smikros / mikros* is that, since sN > N intervocalically is regular in Greek, the *s* was lost in cases where a preceding word began with a vowel, e.g. *ho smikros* (treated as one phonological word), but not elsewhere, and the alternants were then lexicalized as two variants of the same word.

Comment: Isn't the the nix : snow correspondence generally connected to the s-mobile phenomenon ?

Comment: @czypsu Not that I know of. All the branches in which you would expect *sn-* to be retained have a cognate beginning with this cluster: Germanic (English *snow*), Slavic (Slovene *sneg*), Goidelic (Modern Irish *sneachta*), etc.

Answer (score 7):

As Sihler puts it, [in Latin] "an s is lost before most voiced consonants" (para 225), cf. Meiser "*(Konsonant+) s schwindet im Anlaut vor Nasal.*" Thus, in Anlaut (word-initial) clusters *sn, *sm, *sl the *s is lost. He admits that for *sm and *sl the evidence is "meagre." There is no written evidence coming from Latin; this is a reconstruction (i.e. educated guess) based on evidence coming from other IE languages and from the development of Latin Inlaut sn, sm, sl clusters - there is written evidence for the latter. Presumably, the change was s => z=> h (?) => 0

> Latin nix 'snow' <= Proto-Italic *sn(e)iw- (de Vaan)
>
> Latin nido 'nest' <= Proto-Italic *nizdo- (de Vaan)
>
> Latin cena 'meal' <= Proto-Italic *kert(e)snā- (de Vaan), cf. Oscan kersnu, Umbrian śesna, Old Latin cesnas

Leumann 1977 adds that Anlaut *sn, *sl, *sm were retained in the Sabellian (or Sabellic) group (para 194), i.e *not* in Latin:

> Latin no nare - Umbrian SNATU (Meiser), Proto-Italic *(s)nāje/o- (de Vaan)

With ***gn**, there is **actual written evidence** coming from Old Latin, e.g. gnosco (nosco) or gnatus (natus) (para 220); cf. Meiser "*Anlautender Velar schwindet vor n*." This process must have happened by the second century BCE (Meiser 1998, Weiss 2009), cf. still gn- in GNATEIS (122 BCE), as opposed to the very first n- NATVM (117 BCE). Presumably, the change was gn => ŋn => nn

[will add more later]

Comment: Perhaps *_sn_ > _n_ belongs together with changes such as *_-zd- > _-d-_, as in _nīdus_ "nest" < * *nizdo-*?

Comment: @user8017 of course.